# Filtering a large list by Month/Year

Tags: filter, large-lists

I've got a large list (85-100k items) in SP2013 that the user wants to filter by month and year (each month of data is 2,500-4,000K items), preferably selecting from drop downs.  (Clarification:  Users will filter by year month routinely. It needs to perform reasonably, so it needs to be based off of indexed columns)

Trouble is, the date they want to sort by is a basic datetime value, and I'm not finding anything built-in to create this type of UI.  (Select month and year, click "GO", get filtered items)

The existing solutions I see for searching by month involve computed columns, however large lists can only filter on indexed columns, and computed columns are not supported for indexing.

How can I accomplish this?  (NOTE:  I realize I'll probably have to do some custom coding, and that's fine.  I want to find a reasonably simple solution involving the least custom coding.)

Answer (score 1):

Index on the Calculated column is not supported.

As an workaround you can create a view and filter it by as per date. But it is required extra efforts. Check this for more information: [Manage large lists and libraries](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Manage-large-lists-and-libraries-in-Office-365-b4038448-ec0e-49b7-b853-679d3d8fb784)

Or

**SETUP DAILY TIME WINDOW FOR LARGE QUERIES**

This could be a great option if you can limit large queries to only be executed during certain times of the day. This could be useful if your users need to pull large amounts of data or run custom queries during a specified time period during the day.

Comment: I've already posted in the OP that I am aware that indexes on calculated columns are not supported.  I am already versed in the basics of large lists.  My issue is how do I give my users what they need with minimal custom coding.  This answer contains nothing relevant to my question.